# Group Box Plots for different numerical variables in one figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a data frame with several numerical variables and I would like to create box plots for each variable and group them in one figure. So each variable should have its own box plot and all these box plots should be in 1 figure.How can I do that in Seaborn or Matplotlib?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *a data frame with several numerical variables*, why don't you create a sample data frame as you described and include in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do with seaborn:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

num_col_list = ['A','B','C','D']
sns.boxplot(data=df.melt(value_vars=num_col_list),
            x='variable', y='value')
```

Output:

[image]

Or with just pandas/matplotlib:

```
df.boxplot(column=num_col_list)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I would prefer subplots instead of 1 chart. Would that be possible?

Comment: `for x in num_col_list:    fig,ax=plt.subplots();    df[[x]].boxplot(ax=ax)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `pandas` data frame you can use the [`boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) function:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4),columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I would prefer subplots instead of 1 chart. Would that be possible?